# react firestore sub collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get a list of cars for a customer

```
clients:
w21rffa3:
name: Johny
phone: 123123
cars:
fn1jnr12:
brand: AUDi
model: a6
number: 24f1
dsdasgf122:
brand: AUDi
model: a3
number: 62s14
```

**My code**

```
const ref = firestore().collection('clients');
const [clientsList, setClientsList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  return ref.onSnapshot(clientsSnapshot => {
    const clients = [];
    const cars = [];
    clientsSnapshot.forEach(client => {
      const carsRef = ref.doc(client.id).collection('cars').onSnapshot(carsSnapshot => {
        carsSnapshot.forEach(car => {
          if (car.data().brand.length > 0) {
            const {
              brand,
              model,
              number
            } = car.data();
            cars.push({
              id: car.id,
              brand,
              model,
              number,
            });
          }
        });
        //Good result`

        console.log('After forEach: ', cars);
      });
      //Bad result
      console.log('After snapshot: ', cars);
      const {
        name,
        phone
      } = client.data();
      clients.push({
        id: client.id,
        name,
        phone,
        cars: cars,
      });
    });
    setClientsList(clients);
  });
}, []);
```

cars list for customers

Comment: Please, elaborate a bit, clarify what is the actual issue you having, what is not going as expected. Or if you are completely out of ideas of what to do and how to do - please, clarify the data structure you have and the expected behavior.
From what I see in your code - `good result` and `bad result` - `bad result` scripts are executed before `good result` due to `onSnapshot` is async, and you pass a callback function to it, which will be executed when data is available from firebase, so a bit "later" than the rest of the code..

Comment: i have firestore subcollection(`cars`), and i wanna get `cars` collection for `client`,

Comment: but my `client.cars` empty

Answer (score 1):

The error you facing is due to misuse/misunderstanding of how async/callback-based functions works. As I said in my comment - `good result` and `bad result` - `bad result` scripts are executed before `good result` due to onSnapshot is `async`, and you pass a callback function to it, which will be executed when data is available from firebase, so a bit "later" than the rest of the code.

Now about what can be done. The code is a bit tricky and I didnt really test it, so if anything - please, let me know.

```
const [clientsList, setClientsList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  let carsUnsubscribeFns = [];
  const clientUnsubscribeFn = ref.onSnapshot((clientsSnapshot) => {
    // Reset everything and stop previously created listeners for Cars
    setClientsList([]);
    carsUnsubscribeFns.forEach((x) => x());
    carsUnsubscribeFns = [];

    clientsSnapshot.forEach((c) => {
      const { name, phone } = c.data();
      
      const client = { id: c.id, name, phone };
      // In case you dont want to use optional chaining, 
      // remove the const client = ... line above
      // and uncomment the line below
      // but optional chaining is prefered anyway
      // const client = { id: c.id, name, phone, cars: [] };
      
      const carsUnsubscribeFn = ref
        .doc(client.id)
        .collection("cars")
        .onSnapshot((carsSnapshot) => {
          // Mutate the Client object directly
          client.cars = carsSnapshot.docs
            .map((x) => ({ id: x.id, ...x.data() }))
            .filter((x) => x.brand?.length > 0);
          // mark ClientsList as updated to force a rerender
          // due to we mutated one of the entities inside
          setClientsList((curr) => [...curr]);
        });
      carsUnsubscribeFns.push(carsUnsubscribeFn);
      setClientsList((curr) => {
        curr.push(client);
        return [...curr];
      });
    });

    // clean-up function returned from hook to stop all the listeners
    return () => {
      [clientUnsubscribeFn, ...carsUnsubscribeFns].forEach((x) => x());
    };
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: ` ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: @ВУСАЛАБУШОВ At which code line it happens?

Comment: `
{client.cars.map((car, j) => {
  return (
   <Textkey={j}>{car.brand} {car.model} {car.number}</Text>
  );
 })
}
`

Comment: @ВУСАЛАБУШОВ Thats pretty normal, as you can see from the code - Client is loaded first and then it gets updated later, when nested onSnapshot listeners are executed. So initially, when added to an array, `client` does not have `cars` property. I will tweak my code a bit, but if that kind of situations happen - use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). So it will be `{client.cars?.map((car, j) =>....`

Please, tell me if it works for you.

Comment: yes it works, but now adding a new client has stopped working

Comment: `
export const createNewClient = async client => {
  await addDoc(collection(db, 'clients'), {
    name: client.name,
    phone: client.phone,
  });
};
`

Comment: @ВУСАЛАБУШОВ It is not adding anything to database, or when you add this - nothing is rendered with my code? Or any other symptoms? Honestly, im not sure how my code could affect the addDoc part